# How to turn a list of lists of strings into list of list of lists of strings

Tags: python

I have a list of lists of strings. It looks like this:

```html
[['okay'],
 ['d', 'so'],
 ['i', 'guess']]
```

I want further nest each string inside of list so it looks like this:

```html
[[['okay']],
 [['d'], ['so']],
 [['i'], ['guess']]]
```

Please advise on how to do this. Thank you.

Comment: I added an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following list comprehension

```
[[[s2] for s2 in s1] for s1 in l]
```

Running example:

```py
>>> l =  [['okay'],
 ['d', 'so'],
 ['i', 'guess']]
>>> [[[s2] for s2 in s1] for s1 in l]
[[['okay']], [['d'], ['so']], [['i'], ['guess']]]
```